# Primary and secondary groups

Tags: permissions, users, group

I've got the basics of primary and secondary groups down, but still have some questions I can't seem to find solid answers to:

1. Can many users belong to the same primary group?
2. Can one user's primary group be a secondary group of another user?

Comment: The answers to your questions are "YES" and "YES".

Comment: The reason you didn't find explicit answers is probably that nobody bothers listing every arbitrary restriction that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, they can.

   ```
   $ id foo
   uid=1002(foo) gid=1002(foo) groups=1002(foo)
   $ id bar
   uid=1003(bar) gid=1003(bar) groups=1003(bar)
   ```

   Changing the primary group of user `foo` to `bar` which is the primary group for user `bar`:

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -g bar foo
   ```

   Now:

   ```
   $ id foo
   uid=1002(foo) gid=1003(bar) groups=1003(bar)
   $ id bar
   uid=1003(bar) gid=1003(bar) groups=1003(bar)
   ```
2. Yes, it can be.

   ```
   $ id foo
   uid=1002(foo) gid=1002(foo) groups=1002(foo)
   $ id bar
   uid=1003(bar) gid=1003(bar) groups=1003(bar)
   ```

   Adding user `bar` to group `foo` which is the primary group of user `foo`:

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -a -G foo bar
   ```

   Now:

   ```
   $ id foo
   uid=1002(foo) gid=1002(foo) groups=1002(foo)
   $ id bar
   uid=1003(bar) gid=1003(bar) groups=1003(bar),1002(foo)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of the user, he has a primary group and 0 or more secondary groups.

From the perspective of the group, it has 0 or more members.

A group that is the primary group for one or more users can be both a secondary or primary group for other users.